# How to fetch all data from XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to fetch the data from a `XML` column. This is the query and below it is the xml column data

```
SELECT 
    [PQDAdvice].value('(/Advice//DORowData/PrimaryValue/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PrimaryValue,
    [PQDAdvice].value('(/Advice//DORowData/ListValue1/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ListValue1
FROM 
    PatQD 
WHERE
    PQDPatID = '4c983bd8-da00-4395-80bb-a383b21313d5'
```

XML contents:

```
<Advice>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Diet and Nutrition</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Salt Restriction</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Water Consumption</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
</Advice>
```

The issue I am getting that only one column I am getting instead of all column

```
Primary            |ListValue1
Diet and Nutrition |Advice
```

Instead of

```
Primary            |ListValue1
Diet and Nutrition |Advice
Salt Restriction   |Advice
Water Consumption  |Advice
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<Advice>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Diet and Nutrition</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Salt Restriction</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Water Consumption</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
</Advice>'

SELECT 
    t.c.value('PrimaryValue[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as PrimaryValue,
    t.c.value('ListValue1[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as ListValue1
FROM @xml.nodes('Advice/DORowData') t(c)
```

Output -

```
PrimaryValue            ListValue1
----------------------- ------------
Diet and Nutrition      Advice
Salt Restriction        Advice
Water Consumption       Advice
```

Your query -

```
SELECT
    PrimaryValue = t.c.value('PrimaryValue[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)'),
    ListValue1 = t.c.value('ListValue1[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)')
FROM PatQD
CROSS APPLY PQDAdvice.nodes('Advice/DORowData') t(c)
where PQDPatID = '4c983bd8-da00-4395-80bb-a383b21313d5'
```

Comment: not getting it as the column name where xml is present is [PQDAdvice] and table name is PatQD then how to apply this

Comment: Please check the update.. And few words about performance - http://blog.devart.com/xml-xquery-perfomance-issues.html

Comment: @Devart 'cause so many users forget / don't know about voting and accepting SO profs have to help each other :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<Advice>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Diet and Nutrition</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Salt Restriction</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
    <DORowData>
        <PrimaryValue>Water Consumption</PrimaryValue>
        <ListValue1>Advice</ListValue1>
    </DORowData>
</Advice>';

SELECT DoRowData.value('PrimaryValue[1]','varchar(max)') AS PrimaryValue
      ,DoRowData.value('ListValue1[1]','varchar(max)') AS ListValue1
FROM @x.nodes('/Advice/DORowData') AS One(DORowData)
```